# MySql Joining 2 counts in one select

Tags: mysql

I have 2 working queries I want to join into one and produce 4 columns as below. Can anyone help please? I thought a Union would work but it seems to add Volume Loaded and Volume Useable into the same column.

```
Supplier | SCP | Volume Loaded | Volume Useable
===============================================
```

Query 1:

```
SELECT sd.dataprovider AS Supplier, LEFT(sd.SourceCodePrefix, 2) AS SCP, COUNT(*) AS `Volume Loaded` FROM sourcedescription sd
JOIN customerafterimport cai
ON cai.`SourceCode` = sd.`SourceCodePrefix`
JOIN importcustomerpack icp
ON icp.`Id` = cai.`ImportPackId`
GROUP BY LEFT(sd.SourceCodePrefix, 2)
```

Query 2:

```
SELECT sd.dataprovider AS Supplier, LEFT(sd.SourceCodePrefix, 2) AS SCP,  COUNT(*) AS `Volume Useable` FROM sourcedescription sd
JOIN customerafterimport cai
ON cai.`SourceCode` = sd.`SourceCodePrefix`
JOIN importcustomerpack icp
ON icp.`Id` = cai.`ImportPackId`
WHERE isRemovedValidate IS NULL
AND IsRemovedSuppress IS NULL 
AND IsRemovedDeDup IS NULL
AND IsRemovedCleanse IS NULL 
AND IsRemovedPostcodeCleanse IS NULL 
AND IsRemovedSuppressTPS IS NULL
AND IsRemovedCleanseProfanity IS NULL
GROUP BY LEFT(sd.SourceCodePrefix, 2)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT q1.Supplier, q1.SCP, `Volume Loaded`, `Volume Useable`
  FROM ( query 1 ) as q1
  JOIN ( query 2 ) as q2
    ON q1.Supplier = q2.Supplier AND q1.SCP = q2.SCP
```